# Flutter how can i map a list and pass it between screens

Tags: flutter

I am stuck at passing my data list through pages. I have a list of data which i am showing by ListViewbuilder and i need to pass the data of a list in next page. But its showing error of `<String, dynamic> is not a subtype of 'List<dynamic>` I know error is because the second page expect a list or something but i am passing a list so why its showing ? or i need to map or something ?

My code

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class OrderDetails extends StatefulWidget {
  final List text;

  // receive data from the FirstScreen as a parameter
  OrderDetails({Key key, @required this.text}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _OrderDetailsState createState() => _OrderDetailsState();
}

class _OrderDetailsState extends State<OrderDetails> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(widget.text);

    double stackWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;
    double stackHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(  centerTitle: true,backgroundColor: Colors.white, leading: IconButton(
        icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Colors.black),
        onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
      ), title: Text('Order#314313', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),),),
      body: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
         Padding(
           padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
           child: Row(
             mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
             children: <Widget>[
               Text('Custom Information', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'SFPROBOLD', fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 15),),
               Text('Delivery', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'SFPROBOLD', fontSize: 14, color: Color(0xffea6c7b), fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)
             ],
           ),
         ),
          Container(
            width: double.infinity,
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Text('Mohammad Bilal', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'SFPROBOLD', fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 17),),
                  SizedBox(height: stackHeight * 0.004,),
                  Text('+966 59 11111', style: TextStyle( fontSize: 14, color: Colors.grey),),
                  SizedBox(height: stackHeight * 0.01,),
                  Container(
                    height: stackHeight * 0.001,
                    color: Color(0xffeaeaea),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: stackHeight * 0.01,),
                  Text('Home | Eastern Ring Road', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'SFPROBOLD', fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 17),),
                  SizedBox(height: stackHeight * 0.004,),
                  Text('6, Building 9, Second floor, Lulu', style: TextStyle( fontSize: 14, color: Colors.grey),),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Items Ordered', style: TextStyle( fontSize: 15),),
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                  child: Container(
                    width: stackWidth * 0.1,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Color(0xff008ac7),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5))
                    ),

                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                      child: Center(child: Text('PAID', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 9),)),
                    ),
                  ),
                )              ],
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(

                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text('2x', style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff17b39e), fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                      SizedBox(width: stackWidth * 0.04,),
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text('Chicken biryani', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'SFPROBOLD', fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 17),),
                          Text('Leg peice', style: TextStyle( fontSize: 14, color: Colors.grey),),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Text('450 SAR', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'SFPROBOLD', fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 17),),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: stackHeight * 0.001,
            color: Color(0xffeaeaea),
          ),
          Container(
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
              child: Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Row(

                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text('2x', style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff17b39e), fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),),
                      SizedBox(width: stackWidth * 0.04,),
                      Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text('Chicken karahi', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'SFPROBOLD', fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 17),),
                          Text('Extra spicy', style: TextStyle( fontSize: 14, color: Colors.grey),),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  Text('450 SAR', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'SFPROBOLD', fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 17),),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Container(
            height: stackHeight * 0.001,
            color: Color(0xffeaeaea),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Text('Total (incl, Tax)', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 15,),),
                Text('65 SR', style: TextStyle(fontFamily: 'SFPROBOLD', fontSize: 15, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),)
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly ,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width: stackWidth * 0.35,
                  height: stackHeight * 0.07,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: Color(0xff17b39e),
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5))
                  ),
                  child: Center(child: Text('Accept', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),))
                ),
                Container(
                    width: stackWidth * 0.35,
                    height: stackHeight * 0.07,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Color(0xfffe6c6c),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5))
                    ),
                    child: Center(child: Text('Cancel', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),))
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),

          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly ,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                    width: stackWidth * 0.35,
                    height: stackHeight * 0.07,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Color(0xff7d5f93),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5))
                    ),
                    child: Center(child: Text('Ready', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),))
                ),
                Container(
                    width: stackWidth * 0.35,
                    height: stackHeight * 0.07,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Color(0xfffe6c6c),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5))
                    ),
                    child: Center(child: Text('Cancel', style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),))
                )
              ],
            ),
          )
    ],
    ),
    );
  }
}
```

Second page code where i am trying to get data

```
class OrderDetails extends StatefulWidget {
  final List text;

  // receive data from the FirstScreen as a parameter
  OrderDetails({Key key, @required this.text}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _OrderDetailsState createState() => _OrderDetailsState();
}
```

I need help to print the list in second page.

Comment: where does `posts` get value, show us what and how is stored inside the `posts`.

Comment: @manofknowledge i have added my full code now

Comment: you misunderstood I asked the code where the data is applied to the `posts`, the code you provided is for second page.

Comment: @manofknowledge the code i providied is for first page where the all things are calling i need to pass the data on second page and just print it not showing anywhere in second page now.

Answer (score 0):

You should set the generic type of the List in the receiving widget.

```
class OrderDetails extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<String, dynamic> text;

  // receive data from the FirstScreen as a parameter
  OrderDetails({Key key, @required this.text}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _OrderDetailsState createState() => _OrderDetailsState();
}
```

Comment: i try to add same as you say List<String, dynamic> but its showing error in this line The type 'List' is declared with 1 type parameters, but 2 type arguments were given.